# Difference of MD5 Hash in R-Librarys - MD5 for serialized objects

Tags: r, serialization, openssl, md5, digest

I want to calculate a MD5 Hash for an R Object. This is usually done with the serialized object. I am aware of two differect R libs that can calculate MD5 hashes - the digest library and the openssl library. But these two return different hash values. Here is an example fore the openssl library:

```
test <- 1:100

library(openssl )
md5(serialize(test, connection = NULL))
# returns: md5 23:a8:b3:40:9e:08:a0:3d:30:6e:3d:3d:cb:fe:21:57
```

Now the example for the digest library:

```
library(digest)
digest(test,"md5",serialize = T)
# returns: [1] "83777773fa047247723ad5a255963144"
```

## Why are these hash values different?

Comment: Did you try reading the source code?

Comment: Yes, i looked at the code of the digest function which serializes the input the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

`digest` skips some leading bits if the object is serialized.

For example:

```
> .t <- serialize(test, connection = NULL)
> md5(.t[seq(15, length(.t))])
md5 83:77:77:73:fa:04:72:47:72:3a:d5:a2:55:96:31:44
```

### Long answer

The result of `serialize(1:100, connection = NULL)` is different if the R version is different.

According to the source code of [`base::serialize`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b664e701024a766a89f9434238e7d9cb70e14446/src/main/serialize.c#L1310), R writes some integers which represent the R version during the serialization.

`digest::digest` skips these bits before calculating md5sum, so the result will be consistent.

Comment: Thank you so much for the details!