# compare md5 of an object in memory to the md5 of it as an .Rds

Tags: r, serialization, hash, md5

I'd like a way to compare the md5sum of an object in memory to that of an .Rds file of the same object and get identical hashes.

My naive attempt, which does not produce identical hashes:

```r
library(tools)
library(digest)

digest(c(1,2,3), algo = "md5")
#> [1] "af9e5c24af013c970922362b8850b060"

saveRDS(c(1,2,3), "123.Rds")

digest("123.Rds", algo = "md5", file = TRUE)
#> [1] "efb450974fefa662a54d1a2563a4f03b"
md5sum("123.Rds") # redundant
#>                            123.Rds 
#> "efb450974fefa662a54d1a2563a4f03b"
```

I'm aware that [`serialize()` includes the R version in the serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874958/difference-of-md5-hash-in-r-librarys-md5-for-serialized-objects), so if saveRDS() is doing this too, which I suspect it is, then maybe what I am looking for is a saveRDS() that doesn't do that? I may work on projects across multiple R versions, and I'd like a solution here that will give identical results across (non-ancient) versions of R.

Comment: Thanks. If I'm careful to always save the accompanying digest whenever I save the rds, is there a benefit to unpacking and validating the data, or wouldn't it be sufficient to just compare the digest of the object in memory to the saved digest? The motivation for me is to avoid loading any data that I know is identical to what I already have in memory.

Comment: On day 1 I save an .Rds of some data. On day 2 I do some code refactoring or package updates that hopefully do not change the results, and I want to confirm that the data I have in memory on day 2 is identical to what I saved on day 1, without (1) writing another .Rds or (2) reloading the old .Rds. Having read your comment, it seems like I could simply save the digest of the object on day 1, and compare it to the digest of the object made with refactored code on day 2, without necessarily even needing to make an .Rds at all, which hadn't occurred to me. Does this make sense?

Comment: Day 1 and day 2 could be separated by many actual days, or R versions, or on different operating systems, etc. And hopefully the digests would replicate, and if not, alert me to some breaking change I might have otherwise missed.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to post as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the digest of the rds file will never quite match the digest of the actual data. The rds file typically compresses data and will add metadata information like the file format version so the bytes are different and hence the digest is different.

Instead, considering writing out the digest of the data to a separate file at the same time you write the rds. Then, if you want to compare data later, you can just read the cached digest rather than having to reload the original data. For example

```
save_rds <- function(x, rdsname = paste0(substitute(x), ".rds"), digestname = paste0(rdsname,".digest")) {
  hash <- digest::digest(x, algo = "md5")
  saveRDS(x, rdsname)
  writeLines(hash, digestname)
}
```

You can all this function like

```
save_rds(iris)
```

and it will write out `iris.rds` and `iris.rds.digest`.

Then, if you want to compare data to a hash at some later, point, you can have a helper function like

```
digest_match <- function(x, digestfile) {
  hash <- digest::digest(x, algo = "md5")
  orig_hash <- readLines(digestfile)
  return( hash==orig_hash )
}
```

And can test it with

```
digest_match(iris, "iris.rds.digest")
# [1] TRUE
iris[1,1] <- 10
digest_match(iris, "iris.rds.digest")
# [1] FALSE
```